# HERE maps api (js) problem after traveling back from another link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, here-api, here-maps-rest

I'm building an app with ruby on rails and I just implemented a map service with the 'HERE interactive maps' API in the view, with the javascript code.

It works properly but if I click on a link and then use the browser **'go back'**, when it reload the page, the map turns grey and it loads another working map just under the grey block.
If I use the browser reload botton it reloads everything and it shows again only one working map.

It probably save something then, How can I avoid this behavior and force the script to reload as new?

here some code (just copy and paste from the site but it already doesn’t work)

```
<div id="map" style="height: 500px; margin: 2%; background: grey" > </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // Initialize the  communication with the platform
  var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    'app_id': '....',
    'app_code': '....'
  });
  var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
  var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
    tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
    ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320
  });

  //Initialize map
  var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    defaultLayers.normal.map, {
      pixelRatio: pixelRatio,
      zoom: 12,
      center: { lat: 41.90, lng: 12.5 }
    });

  //for interactions and UI components
  var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
  var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

  ...markers.... 
</script>
```

Comment: Please post some example of your code and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It’s actually just copy and paste from the site but it already doesn’t work

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your js in document ready like this if you're not using jquery:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // rest of your js goes inside here
}, false);
```

or if you have jquery then:

```
$(document).ready ( function() {
   // rest of your js goes inside here
});​
```

Comment: I was searching exactly for something like this. Now I don’t have a second map but the map doesn’t work at the first time, I have to use the reload button, then it works. I'm just a beginner on javascript, do you know another listener I can use to auto reload?

Comment: are there any errors in the browser console on the first load?

Comment: I just noticed it happens only when I go to the link by a button, I suppose it’s because it only load a part of the page (I use render on the controller). No errors on the console

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it’s not the best but I fixed it using this code

```
if (document.readyState=='complete'){
  location.reload();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
   // rest of code 
});
```